# Not able to connect to SMTP port of server

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I have following piece of code, usiong which I am trying to send an email. I am using another server as SMPTClient.

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
message.To.Add(toEmailId);
message.Subject = "test Subject";
message.From = new System.Net.Mail.MailAddress("myid@xyz.com");
message.Body = "This is a system generated email. Please do not reply";
SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("anotherservername"); 
smtp.Send(message);
```

While debuggin, I get error at last line. The error is:

```
An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions SERVER IP :25
```

I found out from internet that My firewall might be blocking me to access that server's port, or is there any setting, configuration which I have missed. Apparently the applications deployed on that server are able to send emails. I am still building one to test.

Comment: Do you perhaps need to specify credentials to access the SMTP server?

Comment: What port are you trying to use on that server for `SMTP`? You haven't specified which port to use for `SMTP`.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: @LukeHennerley You don't need to specify the port, it's 25 by default.

Comment: @CodingGorilla I didn't see a single `?` in said question! :P

Comment: What is the result with command : "telnet <your_server> <your_port>" ? (if it displays "connected", there is no firewall problem)

Comment: @CodingGorilla Indeed it is, that's why I asked which port he is trying to use on that server for his SMTP - incase the port that is open for SMTP isn't infact port 25 and he hasn't realised that it defaults to this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.Net Unable to send Email](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6755741/asp-net-unable-to-send-email)

Comment: @JamesLawruk : In duplicated question the asker was ok with answer. I couldnot find appropriate answer over internet, so asked here.

Comment: @Neozaru: It says not connected ! Is there a way I can find out which port is open then ? Apparently my lead doesnot want me to know the port number!

Comment: @user1820973 : Two solutions. 1. Manually : (try a telnet on 25,587 and 465). 2. Try "nmap" software : It will try each port and determine which service is running on which port

Answer (score 0):

Some servers perform authentication and authorization by checking if you've connected to POP server some time before connecting to SMTP. You should try first connecting and authenticating with POP and afterwards connecting to SMTP.

Historically, email clients first checked and then sent emails in Send&Receive routines, so this was used as poor mans authorization. [Take a look at wikipedia article about **POP before SMTP**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POP_before_SMTP).

---

Another issue which caused this for [some people](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ncl/thread/573f98e3-67cb-4e2b-9d5e-6b815b5ed230) is how server address is provided to [`SmtpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k0y6s613.aspx). You should use constructor which explicitly provides port number instead of appending it to IP/hostname. I.e.

instead of  `new SmtpClient("123.123.123.123:25")`

use  `new SmtpClient("123.123.123.123", 25)`

Comment: If this were the case, he would be receiving an `SmtpException` that noted authentication failed.  I don't think this the case based on the exception message he provided.

Comment: Quite possible, but it completely depends on server implementation. I don't have much experience with this, but it sounds reasonable that server would decide to not respond to a request instead of sending notification about failed authentication. But it seems your right other things could cause this. I've updated my answer.

Comment: No, the SMTP protocol requires specific responses and the SmtpClient class will properly interpret those response codes and raise the approparite `SmtpException`.  That is of course assuming that the SMTP server is not garbage and obeys the protocol, which most do now-a-days.